# Why does the audio tag work for an HTML 4.0 website in Chrome but not Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I know that the audio tag is new with HTML5. However, I wanted to see if it would work on a website I had developed for a Winston Churchill enthusiast about 10-15 years ago.  The URL of the site is winstonisback.com.  I developed the site in HTML4 with the DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

As an experiment, I added the following audio to its homepage.

```
<audio autoplay>
<source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikimedia/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Rule%2CBritannia%21_Instrumental.ogg">
</audio>
```

Surprisingly (to me at least) it works in Google Chrome, but not in Microsoft Edge.  Why?!

Comment: And … does it work in Edge if you change the doctype?

Comment: Changed to <!DOCTYPE html>,@Josh, but same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Ogg Vorbis is coming in Edge 17: https://caniuse.com/vorbis (and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/oggcontainer/ and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/vorbisaudiocodec/)

Chrome doesn't implement different versions of HTML depending on the doctype, and neither does anyone else. I even have a citation for this broad claim: https://crbug.com/48976

The main exception is quirks mode (primarily concerning layout), which for some reason will never die.

The first working draft of HTML5 was published about a decade ago; browser vendors and standards authors work together to ensure that as much as possible remains compatible. This can occasionally break old pages, but a new feature has to clearly conflict with something that's in common use to warrant any sort of band-aid; this certainly wouldn't apply to new features like the audio element.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  I settled on a workaround for the moment.  I converted the .ogg file to .wav and uploaded it to the website.  Then put in a second <source> tag for the .wav version.  Now both browsers play the <audio>.